# Solution to cauchy's problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

> Find the solution for the following Cauchy's problem
>
> $y(1-y^2)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-(1+x-y^2x-y^2)\frac{\partial
> > z}{\partial y}=0, x\geq 0, y\in\mathbb{R}$
>
> $z(x,0)=x, x\geq0$

I found the first integral: $\phi _1=x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}$

Could you please tell me how to continue? I'm stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your characteristic equation is correct.
The general solution is :
$$z(x,y)=F\big(x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}\big)$$
$F(X)$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the condition).

Condition : $z(x,0)=x=F\big(x+\frac{x^2}{2}\big)$

With $\quad X=x+\frac{x^2}{2} \quad\implies\quad  x=-1\pm\sqrt{2X+1}$

$$x=F(X)=-1\pm\sqrt{2X+1}$$
Now the function $F(X)$ is known. We put it into the above general solution where $X=x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}$
$$z(x,y)=-1\pm\sqrt{2\big(x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}\big)+1}$$
$$z(x,y)=-1\pm\sqrt{(x+1)^2-y^2}$$
The sign is determined according to $z(x,0)=x$
$$\boxed{z(x,y)=-1+\sqrt{(x+1)^2-y^2}}$$

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.